# Why do I failed to read Excel 2007 using POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I try to initialize a Workbook object I always get this error:

```
The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

But I followed the office sample to do this, following is my code:

```
File inputFile = new File(inputFileName); 
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

Exception occurs at code line:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

Here is POI jar including:

```
poi-3.8-20120326.jar  
poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar  
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar  
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

Can any guys give me guidance? An example showing how to read a complete Excel 2007 document will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have recheck that your original file is indeed in Office 2007+XML format, right?

**Edit:**

Then, if you are sure the format is ok, and it works for you using the WorkbookFactory.create, you can find the answer in the code of such method:

```
   /**
     * Creates the appropriate HSSFWorkbook / XSSFWorkbook from
     *  the given InputStream.
     * Your input stream MUST either support mark/reset, or
     *  be wrapped as a {@link PushbackInputStream}!
     */
    public static Workbook create(InputStream inp) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
            // If clearly doesn't do mark/reset, wrap up
            if(! inp.markSupported()) {
                    inp = new PushbackInputStream(inp, 8);
            }

            if(POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(inp)) {
                    return new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
            }
            if(POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(inp)) {
                    return new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(inp));
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream");
    }
```

This is the bit that you were missing: `new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(inp))`

Comment: I think my Excel source is no problem.

Comment: Solved. I get reading right by below code:

    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName); 
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

Even it works, I don't know what's difference between below and above code.

Comment: Thanks David Bejar! It creates a appropriate Workbook to a Excel according to its header. Got